# Javascript / jQuery - Tap outside an element on an iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios

I found a great answer on detecting a click outside a div from this question: [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element), which works fantastically.

But I've noticed that it doesn't work on the iPhone when testing my site, if I tap outside the element.

Here is the code (taken directly from that answer)

```
$('html').click(function() {
    //Hide the menus if visible
});

$('#menucontainer').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery

Answer (score 11):

this worked for me :)

```
$('html').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    $('.navbar-flyout').hide();
})
$(".navbar-flyout").on('touchstart',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.addEventListener('click', function (e) { //TODO();});
```

The trick:

```
/*Add this line into only mobile css*/
body{cursor:pointer}
```