# iPhone's on click for appended DIVs

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have a webpage disigned for mobile devices, most of the data is loaded into it via AJAX request and appended to the BODY with jQuery, so far it works just fine.However, when I try to attach an on click listener, the following listener doesn't work for any browser

```
$('[id^="the_content"]').click(function () {
...
});
```

I've solved this problem by using the On() method. the following code work perfectly on all browsers (tested on Chrome,FF,IE,**Safari for windows**). except for the build browser.

```
$(document).on("click",'[id^="the_content"]',function() {
...
});
```

Note that these listeners **does** work for data which was not appended via JS/jQuery

**Note that my code pass W3C HTML5 validation with no errors at all.**

Have anyone faced such a problem?

*div example:*

```
<div id='the_content_id_61'>...</div>
```

Comment: When are you adding the `$.click()` handler? On page load? Or each time you get new content with Ajax, *after* you've appended it to the DOM?

Comment: I tried both non of them work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `click` events, make use of `touch` events.

Refer to the touch Handler function on this **[$(document).click() not working correctly on iPhone. jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3714129/500725)**