# jquery.click() not working in iOS

Tags: jquery, ios

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <a class="button1 selected" id="button1" href="#"><div class="icon"></div><div class="text">Option 1</div></a>
    <a class="button2" id="button2" href="#"><div class="icon"></div><div class="text">Option 2</div></a>
    <a class="button3" id="button3" href="#"><div class="icon"></div><div class="text">Option 3</div></a>
    <a class="button4" id="button4" href="#"><div class="icon"></div><div class="text">Option 4</div></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    alert('button1');
});

$('#button2').click(function() {
    alert('button2');
});
```

Now, this script works perfectly on my PC Browser but it doesn't work on iOS. I've tried this solution too: [$(document).click() not working correctly on iPhone. jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery) but it doesen't work.

I am using on jQuery 1.8.3, no jQuery Mobile (I prefer not to).

Somebody can help me with this?

Comment: It should work fine, but since you say it doesn't: try `$('#button1').on('click touch', function() {...})` instead.

Comment: Just tested on my iphone and it's working.

Comment: I think the real problem is that you're wrapping a pair of `<a>` tags around some `<div>`s. This shouldn't be illegal, but some browsers may balk at it.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try to add a pointer cursor to the button and use .on to bind the click event.

```
$('#button1').css('cursor','pointer');
$(document).on('click', '#button1',  function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('button1');
});
```

Comment: Mobile touchscreens don't have cursors. And your JS is literally equivalent to calling `.click()`; jQuery converts one to the other internally.

Comment: Interesting. Have a reference for that?

Comment: I encountered this problem before and try to do sth like this. Luckily, it works.

Comment: I've no idea why this works (or in fact why `.on('click'...` wasn't working for me) but it does work

Comment: To my suprise, this answer is acually right. Adding "cursor: pointer" actually makes the difference between clickable and not clickable.

Comment: The `event.preventDefault();` missed in my script and was causing though there was nothing which should have been obviously prevented.

Comment: OK very weird, i tried multiple solutions (on-click, touch events, and more) and already noticed this one (in CSS) in a few places and so nearly discarded it.. Adding CURSOR:POINTER via JS for me however allowed it to work every-time! Nasty looking however but I can live with it.

Comment: It's not working in 2021

Answer (score 11):

I came across this:
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/02/mouse_event_bub.html

In short, one of these conditions needs to be met for iOS browsers to generate click events from touch-events:

> 1. The target element of the event is a link or a form field.
> 2. The target element, or any of its ancestors up to but not including the `<body>`, has an explicit event handler set for any of the mouse events. This event handler may be an empty function.
> 3. The target element, or any of its ancestors up to and including the document has a cursor: pointer CSS declarations.

Comment: adding `onclick=""` on a page-wrapping element worked for me. Setting `style="cursor: pointer"` on that element also worked, but since this page isn't mobile-only, that wasn't a great solution for desktop users.

Comment: Neither worked for me... unbelievable...

Answer (score 2):

A general solution might be something like this:

JS

```
const IS_IOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;

if (IS_IOS) {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('ios');
}
```

CSS

```
.ios,
.ios * {
    // causes dom events events to be fired
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yacuzo's answer is the most exhaustive.
But I want to add the 4th trick (my favorite):

`$('div:first').on('click', $.noop);`

And it doesn't matter whether the first div is a parent of your target element or not!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to this issue is to just add `cursor: pointer;` to the style (CSS) of the element that you are targeting.

```
#button1 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Alternatively, this could be added inline:

```
<a class="button1 selected" id="button1" href="#" style="cursor: pointer;"><div class="icon"></div><div class="text">Option 1</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#button1').css('cursor','pointer');

this function not work on cordova 10.0、Xcode 13.2

I use this function Solve the problem↓

```
document.getElementById('chatpage').click();
document.getElementById('chatpage').click();
```

.click two time can solve the problem on me

For your reference