# Click event on iOS won't work except when clicking on image... why?

Tags: jquery, ios, click, mobile-safari

I'm trying to get a Div to open when it's clicked and close when anything else on the page is clicked and it works fine on all browsers except iOS, where it only closes if you click on an image. There are several similar questions on here, mainly this one sounds like my problem ([$(document).click() not working correctly on iPhone. jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery)) but sorry, I can't get any of them to work - can anyone help?

And **WHY** is this the case - what's special about an image/jQuery in iOS?

HTML:

```
<p>Click on the box to show the div</p>
<div id="toolbar">
    <div id="searchbox">
        <p>Click anywhere else to hide the div</p>
    </div>
</div>
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Example_image.png" width="240" height="240" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#toolbar').click(function (e) {
    $('#searchbox').fadeIn();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$(document).click(function (e) {
    $('#searchbox').fadeOut();
});
```

});

See fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/atype/PqdTK/7/

Comment: Hi have you found out a solution for this issue? I am also facing same issue

Comment: No, not yet unfortunately, I'm really interested to know why it works when you click on an image but not the rest of the page though.

Comment: Try adding cursor:pointer as a css style.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that for elements that aren't stricly hrefs, that the first press is a "hover" event and the second press of the finger is the "click".