# Jquery using .on() when element doesn't exist not working on ios7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios7

I'm trying to use jquery "on" method to listen to click event on an element that might not be in page yet. (in my example the element is in page), however it doesn't work on iOS7

tested and working on:
chrome 32.0.1700.72 m
ff 26
Android 4.3 Samsung s3

Not working on my iPhone 4s running ios7

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MPYKX/

HTML:

```
<div id="clickable">Click me</div>
```

JS:

```
var onClick = function () {
    alert("ok");
};

$(document).ready( function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#clickable", onClick);
});
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery

Comment: It may be worth looking into `ontouch` events.. as you don't really "click" an element on touch devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click events don't work on iOS, you'd have to use the [touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchstart), [touchmove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchmove) and [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchend) events to work out if the users tapped the screen.

Comment: Thanks, 
But I'm a bit confused, the other way of using a click event does work:
`code`$("clickable").click(onClick)  `code`
Does work both on desktop, android and ios7.
but adding touchend to :
`code`$(document).on("click touchend", "#clickable", onClick); `code`
triggers the events twice.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.event = (ua.match(/iPad|Android/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";
$(element).on(app.event, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
```