# checkboxes not check through button with js/jquery in Apple devices

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ios, ipad

when i open website in iphone or ipad then its checkboxes not check through button. this is my code

html:

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn-u btn-u-dark-blue" id="btnpvtperson" style="border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px !important;" >Privatperson</button>
<input type="checkbox" name="delAnn[]" id="checkpvtperson" value="pvt" class="home_type istrow btn-u" style="display:none"></td>
```

js:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnpvtperson', function()
{
    if($("#checkpvtperson").prop("checked") == false)
    {
        $("#checkpvtperson").attr('checked', true);
        $("#btnpvtperson").removeClass("btn-u-dark-blue");
        $("#btnpvtperson").addClass("btn-u-dark-light");
    } else {
        $("#checkpvtperson").attr('checked', false);
        $("#btnpvtperson").removeClass("btn-u-dark-light");
        $("#btnpvtperson").addClass("btn-u-dark-blue");
    }
});
```

Comment: change `.attr()` to `.prop()`.

Comment: Check it in : [$(document).click() not working correctly on iPhone. jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery Prop function in versions above 1.6 take as below:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnpvtperson', function()
            {
                if($("#checkpvtperson").prop("checked") == false)
                {
                    $("#checkpvtperson").prop('checked', true);
                    $("#btnpvtperson").removeClass("btn-u-dark-blue");
                    $("#btnpvtperson").addClass("btn-u-dark-light");
                } else {
                    $("#checkpvtperson").prop('checked', false);
                    $("#btnpvtperson").removeClass("btn-u-dark-light");
                    $("#btnpvtperson").addClass("btn-u-dark-blue");
                }
            });
```