# Close lightbox on clicking outside not working in iPhone/iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

Below is the code I am using. Clicking outside closes the lightbox in Windows and Android, but not in iPhone and iPad.

**JS:**

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).has('.pop-up').length) {
    $('.pop-up-overlay').hide();
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pop-up-overlay">
  <div class="pop-up">
    <p>Popup contents goes here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To see the result you should add two code snippets in one edit, you have added both two languages separately

Comment: I am new here, and this is my first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this for ios:

```js
    $(document).on("click touchstart", function(event) {
      if ($(event.target).has('.pop-up').length) {
        $('.pop-up-overlay').hide();
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pop-up-overlay">
  <div class="pop-up">
    <p>Popup contents goes here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Similar question was asked in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery)

Comment: Above code is not working on Safari(Mac) and Chrome(Mac). Will you please help me again?