# CSS animations are blocking touch events on iOS

Tags: ios, css

I'm using this code to make a element enlarge a few pixels when hovered, but for some reason it's blocking touch event (click) on iOS. Any idea?

```
.hvr-grow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
.hvr-grow:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: I would try removing translateZ, backface-visibility, or both.

Comment: Kyle Horkley - that was causing the issue. Fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is on iOS specifically, it may not be the CSS transform event blocking the touch/click event. In iOS Safari, if you want a `div` to have a click event, it must either have a directly bound `onclick` handler, or the CSS property `cursor: pointer`. This is how Safari knows that a div is "clickable", and it's a weird niche of Safari that I don't think exists on other mobile browsers.

See this post for more details: [$(document).click() not working correctly on iPhone. jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery)

But in short, I'd suggest adding `cursor: pointer` to `.hvr-grow` and seeing if that makes a difference. Your `:hover` CSS won't register on mobile, so you won't get the grow effect anyway.

Comment: That was helpful, but Kyle Horkley comment was the working answer. Thank you thought! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612896/css-animations-are-blocking-touch-events-on-ios/32614290#comment53076856_32612896