# jQuery click not working in iOS?

Tags: jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have added some simple javascript to a site:

```
jQuery(document).click(function(){
  alert('click');
});
```

...and it only fires in iOS when someone clicks on an actual anchor element, button element, or on something with `cursor: pointer;` CSS.

Specifically, I am seeing this with the Bootstrap 3 fixed navbar menu. When it's open, I have added:

```
jQuery(document).click(function(){
  jQuery('#navbar-collapse.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

to ensure that it closes no matter where someone clicks.

This is not working in iOS (verified on iPhone 4, iPhone 6/6+ and iPads).

It seems that jQuery click events only register on "clickable" elements (A, BUTTON, etc) or elements with  `cursor: pointer;` CSS or `onClick='...something...'` or even or `onClick=''` HTML attributes.

So, my question. Is this just me? Does anyone else see this?

Comment: It works for me on iOS: http://jsfiddle.net/k98Bn/39/

Comment: It works for you because you are using a clickable element (button) as he said in the question

Comment: Reading this seems to indicate that it is definitily an iOS issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery

Comment: Definitely an iOS "issue". It seems that this is by-design:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: ?? The example is using `jQuery(document).click` as specified in the question. `document` is not a button

Comment: Try, with an iOS device, tapping in the whitespace with the menu open. It should close the menu if the document's onClick even fires as one would expect.

Comment: I'm testing on iPhone 6 and the menu closes when you click _anywhere_ in the document. This Fiddle also works for me on iOS: https://jsfiddle.net/eyxwossq/

Comment: Maybe something strange is happening with JSFiddle. Try this (clean):
http://karlwilbur.net/so-35046771.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[How apple handles events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

By design you *need* to use a clickable element. So yes, everyone will experience this issue unless they take care of it with a solution similar to this. If it can't be *expected* to be clicked then it won't be seen that way by IOS.

An excerpt from apples developer page.

> Making Elements Clickable
>
> Because of the way Safari on iOS creates events to emulate a mouse,
>   some of your elements may not behave as expected on iOS. In
>   particular, some menus that only use mousemove handlers, as in Listing
>   6-1, need to be changed because iOS doesn’t recognize them as
>   clickable elements.
>
> Listing 6-1  A menu using a mouseover handler

```
<span onmouseover = "..."
  onmouseout  = "..."
WHERE TO BUY
</span>
```

> To fix this, add a dummy onclick handler, onclick = "void(0)", so that
>   Safari on iOS recognizes the span element as a clickable element, as
>   shown in Listing 6-2.
>
> Listing 6-2  Adding an onclick handler

```
<span onmouseover = "..."
  onmouseout  = "..."
  onclick = "void(0)">
WHERE TO BUY
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's *exactly* what I was looking for.