# removeClass not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

When you click `.menuButton` jquery will add a class named `active`. This Jquery code works on Windows and on Android  except on iOS (Tested with Chrome and Safari).

**HTML5**

```
<div class="menuButton">
  Menu Button
</div>
<div class="navmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
var removeClassVar = true;
$('.menuButton').on('click', function() {
  $('.navmenu').toggleClass('active');
  removeClassVar = false;
});
$('.navmenu').on('click', function() {
  removeClassVar = false;
});
$(document).on('click', function() {
  if (removeClassVar == true) {
      $('.navmenu').removeClass('active');
  }
  removeClassVar = true;
});
```

**CSS3**

```
.menuButton {
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.navmenu {
  display:none;
}
.navmenu.active {
  display:block;
}
```

Problem: When you click on `.menuButton` the menu will show, but when you click on `html` the menu will not run `removeClass('active')`. This problem only occurs on iOS.

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dkg7tyu0/

Updated JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dkg7tyu0/5/

**Update**
Apparently iOS does not work with `on('click'')` however adding the following code will get me a Hello World `$('.menuButton').on('touchstart click', function(){  alert('hello world'); });`. Bad news is that changing my code from `on('click')` to `on('touchstart click')` will not make a difference in removing the class.

Comment: You should bind click event to `document` not `'html'`

Comment: @A.Wolff If I do that it won't remove the `active` class (not on Chrome on Windows).

Comment: How that? https://jsfiddle.net/dkg7tyu0/2/  Anyway you are overcomplicating it here and i'm still not sure what is your expected behaviour  https://jsfiddle.net/dkg7tyu0/3/ ???

Comment: Add .menuButton{ cursor:pointer;} to your css

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry, my bad. Had `'document'` instead of `document`. I have changed it to `document` now but this doesn't make a difference on iOS.

Comment: @DelightedD0D No difference on iOS.

Comment: @Jeff Silly question but do you clear browser cache on IOS?

Comment: Sillier question, but why are you naming a boolean removeClass when a function exists with that name?

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, just be sure I deleted it again but still the same problem.

Comment: @Nikki9696 Just saw that. Changed it now. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Jeff But have you tried this one instead https://jsfiddle.net/dkg7tyu0/3/  If still not working then i don't see what could be the issue on IOS

Comment: @Nikki9696 There is a global `removeClass` function on IOS browser??? But anyway, that's correct OP should avoid so confusing global name variable

Comment: @A.Wolff Tried that JsFiddle and it works on Windows and Android but not on iOS. By the way, I've changed the boolean name ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff not sure, but there's one defined in jquery, which he's using, so it's safest not to do that I think - not sure if IOS might have any bugs with scope

Comment: Oh hey did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery

Comment: @Nikki9696 `$.fn.removeClass()` is defined on jQuery prototype, not window global scope but you are right it is more safe to not do that anyway

Comment: @Nikki9696 I tried it but still no luck.. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $ua = navigator.userAgent;
  var $event = ($ua.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

  $(document).on($event, function(ev) {
    if ($('.navmenu').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.navmenu').toggleClass('active');
    }
  });
  $('.menuButton').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.navmenu').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/fabiovaz/pen/VaPzqz

I really think your problems is $('html').click() on iOS, you can search other solutions (like touch actions) or check if this work `$('html').click(function() { alert('hello world'); });`

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent,
        event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

$(document).on(event, function (ev) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I changed the `$('html').on('click', function(){});` to `$(document).on('click', function(){});` but this does not make a difference. The code above works on Windows and Android, but not on iOS again.

Comment: you changed html cursor pointer? and tested userAgent? I think your problem is about document click function, not at your code.

Comment: So tried the last bit (after your update) and it seems that iOS does not work with `on('click')` However I get an message if I put this code in `$('html').on('touchstart click', function() { alert('hello world'); });` but `touchstart` will not make my menu disappear.

Comment: $('html').on('touchstart', function() { alert('hello world'); });

Comment: I made a mistake, changing to `$(document).on('touchstart', function() { alert('hello world'); });` will get me a Hello World. But it will not make my menu disappear.

Comment: http://codepen.io/fabiovaz/pen/VaPzqz i put more code, please test. (sorry i have android only)

Comment: Thank you! Only the Jquery code was needed and it works now on every device! :)

Comment: Using touch start like this is not advised, as users who are trying to scroll will inadvertently trigger your click event. OP, are you sure you applied cursor:pointer; correctly? That is the verified solution to the problem and I can personally confirm that it works in iOS

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

see here https://jsfiddle.net/dkg7tyu0/1/

```
if (!$('.navmenu').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.navmenu').addClass('active');
      removeClass = false;
    }
```