# class not being added in ios on click of <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, cross-browser

I have the following jQuery code to add a class to a anchor tag when its clicked, the objective is to give the anchor tag a border bottom:

```
$(".breadcrumbs > li > a").click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('hoveractive');
});
```

on Ios this class is never added and so the styles are not applied, Rest of the code is below:

```
.breadcrumbs > li > a.hoveractive {
    border-bottom : 1px solid #f05034;
}
```

HTML::-

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
     <li><a href="/en">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="/en/about-desuninr">About Desunin<sup>®</sup> </a></li>
     <li>Interesting links</li>
 </ul>
```

basically i just want the class to be added for a fraction of a secound before the page refreshes and goes to the next link, but this does't seem to be happening.

If i change my code to the below,

```
$(".breadcrumbs > li > a").click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('hoveractive');
     return false;
});
```

I.E. include a `return false` statement , then the class is added in ios, but that's ofcourse not what i want to be doing , so to summerise my question why is my addClass not working in ios ?

Comment: check out the similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062221/removeclass-not-working-on-ios).

Comment: @jayly amazing ... solved the issue , i still don't understand the `why` click does't work but `touchstart` does.

Comment: here's another helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095868/jquery-click-not-working-in-ios) :)

Comment: @jayly that has to do with event delegation i believe :) .. in this case i think the difference between touchstart and click comes into play -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633297/touchstart-vs-click-what-happens-under-the-hood/9634715#9634715

Comment: awesome, glad you found the answer you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the click event from document and see if that helps,

```
$(document).on('click', '.breadcrumbs > li > a', function(){
 $(this).addClass('hoveractive');
});
```