# Event touchstart doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, addeventlistener

I have some code that generally works, except on iPhone.  When the window loads, this function is called.  When I have the event as `click`, it works just fine on desktop, but not on mobile.  I've tried looking around for solutions for mobile, and `touchstart` seems to be the recommended solution.  But, though it works on emulators, it doesn't work on iPhone (tested on the latest OS version).  Am I missing something?

```
function addXClassOnClick() {
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
      el.parentElement.classList.toggle('x');
    }, false);
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Id include the mobile safari version you are on since it seems relevant. `getElementsByClassName` was introduced in ios safari 9.2 which was released in December for example.

Comment: @omoman added it! It's all on the latest stuff that I'm testing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the document fragment:

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

The anonymous event handler function's default scope is bound to the clicked element, and not to the clicked element's parent, which is the scope that `classList.toggle` should operate on.

(edit: According to the documentation, **forEach** passes `undefined` in as the scope of the callback function when not specified. The DOM element reference `el` has no scope to operate in. It's like the DOM is there, but the scope chain isn't.)

To fix this, either call `classList.toggle` with the correct scope:

```
el.parentElement.classList.toggle.call(el.parentElement.classList, 'x');
```

or call `forEach` with the desired scope as a second argument:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    // omit
}, els);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery).

If you're using an `<a>` tag, everything will work as expected on iPhones and other touch devices. Otherwise, you should add CSS to whatever element with style `cursor: pointer;`.