# toggleClass when tapping on mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm currently applying `toggleClass` (to change colors) on each row of my table:

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('red-c blue-c');
});
```

This works great on my desktop - as soon as I click on a row, the color toggles.  However, on mobile, when I tap on a row, the row stays selected and the color doesn't toggle immediately. It toggles only after I tap on a second row.

I tried using the "touch" and "touchstart" events. Still no luck. The issue I think is that when I tap on a row, it stays selected / highlighted. It's only when I click on a different row that it gets unselected and toggles color.

Comment: I think this is duplicate for [document .click function for touch device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397028/document-click-function-for-touch-device)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: I tried using the "touch" event instead of "touchstart". Still no luck. The issue I think is that when I tap on a row, it stays selected / highlighted. It's only when I click on a different row that it gets unselected and toggles color.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the css style

```
cursor:pointer
```

to your

[details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17490775/3511012)

Comment: it appears to work for iPhones (safari). Just out of curiousity what mobile platform are you using?

Comment: Using Safari on iPhone :) The row I tap on continues to be selected.