# Button onClick not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touch

I tried a whole bunch of things from:
[onClick not working on mobile (touch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch)

[document .click function for touch device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397028/document-click-function-for-touch-device)

However nothing seems to work.

Here's what I have:

```
#modal-close {cursor:pointer;}

<button class="button" id="modal-close">ok</button>

function hideModal(){
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}

 $(function() {
        $('#modal-close').on('click touchstart',function (e) {
            hideModal();
            })
        });
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: USe this '$('#modal-close').on('click touchstart',function () {
            hideModal();
            })'

Comment: i've seen this issue on ios. touch triggers hover state rather than triggering a click event. i believe we used this to solve the problem: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Comment: @RashidJaved Doesn't work

Comment: @RobertBroden Did you do simply just include it or was there any other code involved?

Comment: @blue_zinc another developer included it. it appears to have a Usage section that explains how to implement it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turned out

```
 #modal-close {cursor:pointer;}

<button class="button" id="modal-close">ok</button>

function hideModal(){
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}

 $(function() {
        $('#modal-close').on('click touchstart',function (e) {
            hideModal();
            })
        });
```

Was valid

The thing that got me was `hideModal()` which used `classList` to add or remove classes. I switched it to `className +=` and it worked as supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Change the id of your button to modal_close. This may work for you. The id value acts like an identifier, so there is rule that we cannot use every symbol for naming identifiers.