# Different Javascript behavior between iPad & IPhone

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, ipad

I'm trying to figure out a difference between iPad and iPhone behavior using Javascript.

Using this code to switch between elements by changing class and switching between opacity (previously display:none), it works fine in Android, Desktop and iPad, but iPhone refuses.

I have 6 divs like this here as example:

```
<div id="blue6" onclick="show('id6');" class="switchDivContainer" style="border-bottom:0px;">
```

And code like this to control it

```
function show(elementId) { 
 document.getElementById("id6").className = "hideClass";
 document.getElementById(elementId).className = "MyClass";
}
</script>
```

[Live page can actually be seen here](http://rimaster.se/ricab/)
The blue area should make the images/videos switch, but iPhone says no-no.

[image: This blue area should change image to the left]

The question is really - why does this work like a charm in everything but iPhone.

Comment: I have the same issue on iPad, so instead of using `Click` event i need to use `Touch` event. Try with that.

Comment: That sounds promising. Something like ontouch=""?

Comment: I'm not sure that inline touch event exist, but I do it like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11398089/3888517)

Comment: have you tried adding an eventListener() to listen for the click

Comment: There may be a problem with opacity property on IOS. Try to use opacity together with visibility property, worth a shot.