# How to open dropdowns in mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to open child dropdown on its parent dropdown change event, In my form, I have 10 dropdowns which I need to open one-by-one on dropdown change event of its parent Select.

I tried lots of jquery snippets but those are working on desktop browsers only, NOT in mobile like http://jsfiddle.net/XE73h/444/

I have also tried **size** attribute as `$("#sel").attr("size", 10);` but it is also not working in mobile. (tried in Chrome for Andriod and Safari for iPhone devices)

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the function with click or touch, you could change this:

```
$(document).click( function () {
```

To this:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function () {
```

Or this:

```
$(document).on('click touch', function () {
```

The `touchstart` event fires as soon as an element is touched, the `touch` event is more like a "tap", i.e. a single contact on the surface. You should really try each of these to see what works best for you. On some devices, `touch` can be a little harder to trigger (which may be a good or bad thing - it prevents a drag being counted, but an accidental small drag may cause it to not be fired).
For reference you can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397028/document-click-function-for-touch-device)

Comment: I have used both the methods you suggested none of them is working.
I opened http://jsfiddle.net/XE73h/444/ url in mobile and did the changes but nothing happened.