# The removeClass of the jquery works one beat slower on the mobile(HTML) device

Tags: jquery, class, mobile, click

This is a really strange case.

If I click an element, the class of div disappears immediately both PC and MAC. Using removeClass it was fine that I want.

However mobile devices(iPhone and Android) are something wrong.
When I try to click an element the class does not remove on the screen. But the console print out that the class go away. So I click any area of blank this element show as it normal.

I don't know why this issue happen to mobile device?
What can I do to make the screen show immediate reaction?

```
$(".div").on('click touch', function(){
    var idx = $(this).index(".div");
    if($(this).hasClass("yellow")){
          $(this).removeClass("yellow");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try `touchstart` instead of `touch`

```
$(".div").on('click touchstart', function(){
   var idx = $(this).index(".div");
   if($(this).hasClass("yellow")){
      $(this).removeClass("yellow");
   }
}
```

if Its a dynamic element, u must trigger for body

```
$("body").on('click touchstart', '.div', function(){
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use touchstart

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function () {
```

ref [document .click function for touch device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397028/document-click-function-for-touch-device)