# Change jqueryslidemenu From Hover To Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have been using a script found on [DynamicDrive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/cs...vel_css_menu_2)

for many years now, and it's working fine until recently i discovered that the menu doesnt work on Mobile devices, I noticed i needed to change the event from mouseover to mouseclick since mobile devices don't use mouse.

I've tried to change $curobj.hover(... to $curobj.click(...
but it's not working.
Below is the content of jqueryslidemenu.js

```
//============================================================================
//Update: April 12th, 10: Fixed compat issue with jquery 1.4x

//Specify full URL to down and right arrow images (23 is padding-right to add to top level LIs with drop downs):
var arrowimages={down:['downarrowclass', '../resources/down.gif', 23], right:['rightarrowclass', '../resources/right.gif']}

var jqueryslidemenu={

animateduration: {over: 200, out: 100}, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds

buildmenu:function(menuid, arrowsvar){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var $mainmenu=$("#"+menuid+">ul")
        var $headers=$mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
        $headers.each(function(i){
            var $curobj=$(this)
            var $subul=$(this).find('ul:eq(0)')
            this._dimensions={w:this.offsetWidth, h:this.offsetHeight, subulw:$subul.outerWidth(), subulh:$subul.outerHeight()}
            this.istopheader=$curobj.parents("ul").length==1? true : false
            $subul.css({top:this.istopheader? this._dimensions.h+"px" : 0})
            $curobj.children("a:eq(0)").css(this.istopheader? {paddingRight: arrowsvar.down[2]} : {}).append(
                '<img src="'+ (this.istopheader? arrowsvar.down[1] : arrowsvar.right[1])
                +'" class="' + (this.istopheader? arrowsvar.down[0] : arrowsvar.right[0])
                + '" style="border:0;" />'
            )
            $curobj.hover(
                function(e){
                    var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                    this._offsets={left:$(this).offset().left, top:$(this).offset().top}
                    var menuleft=this.istopheader? 0 : this._dimensions.w
                    menuleft=(this._offsets.left+menuleft+this._dimensions.subulw>$(window).width())? (this.istopheader? -this._dimensions.subulw+this._dimensions.w : -this._dimensions.w) : menuleft
                    if ($targetul.queue().length<=1) //if 1 or less queued animations
                        $targetul.css({left:menuleft+"px", width:this._dimensions.subulw+'px'}).slideDown(jqueryslidemenu.animateduration.over)
                },
                function(e){
                    var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                    $targetul.slideUp(jqueryslidemenu.animateduration.out)
                }
            ) //end hover
            $curobj.click(function(){
                $(this).children("ul:eq(0)").hide()
            })
        }) //end $headers.each()
        $mainmenu.find("ul").css({display:'none', visibility:'visible'})
    }) //end document.ready
}
}

//build menu with ID="myslidemenu" on page:
jqueryslidemenu.buildmenu("myslidemenu", arrowimages)
```

Comment: Can you try replacing hover with on("click", ... , [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/) you can find more info about.

Comment: I tried $curobj.on('click', function(e){... as suggested, but it still didnt work.

Comment: could you try as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397028/document-click-function-for-touch-device)?

Comment: I wish i know exactly what i need to do, i'm not able to relate the solution provided there to my own script

Comment: sorry, I mean using touchstart and/or touch after click, with .on("click ... syntax