# jquery live click bind for mobile webpage

Tags: iphone, jquery

i am making a website for mobile devices, in which i have a list of name and i need to bind click event to the list. i done this using jquery. in all webdevices (android, blackberry, nokia) when i click the list the result will come but nly in iphone the event is not triggering. how can i solve it.

```
<ol id="movie-list">
 <li> Movie 1 </li>
 <li> Movie 2 </li>
 <li> Movie 3 </li>
</ol>

$('#movie-list li").live("click", function() {
 console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5677 - Live Click Events Don't Register On MobileSafari (iPhone)

Apparently that's a jQuery bug. "*The workaround is to add onclick="" to the element you are attaching to....*"

On a different note though, [`.live()` has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

The link provides information on porting to newer methods. If using jQuery 1.7+:

```
$(document).on("click", "#movie-list li", function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery `.on` instead of `.live`

There is typo in your code `'#movie-list li"` should be `"#movie-list li"`

```
$(document).on("click", "#movie-list li", function() {
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

**EDIT:** 
Exact duplicate - [How do I use jQuery for click event in iPhone web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025348/how-do-i-use-jquery-for-click-event-in-iphone-web-application)

Comment: @JaisonJustus check the duplicate answer I posted :)

Comment: @jaison like I said in my answer, this is a known problem. Some elements aren't allowed to trigger clicks in mobile safari. I provide a workaround in my solution...

Comment: i added cursor : pointer to the style of li. now its works fine. testing on devices.. thank you Dipaks and nbrooks