# use ontouchstart() or onclick() depending on device

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, ontouch

first, I know there are a few ways around this, [such as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914568/make-onclick-work-on-iphone) making making the `ontouchstart` and `onclick` the same. But is there a way to check if the users has a smartphone/tablet/touchscreen device vs a laptop or computer, and change the function of `ontouchstart` to `click`? Here's an example of one way to solve it:

```js
var touchScreen = false;
var touches = 0;
var clicks = 0;

document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
  touchScreen = true;

  function touch() {
    touches++;
    console.log(touches);
    console.log(clicks);
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "touches = " + touches + ", clicks = " + clicks;
  }
  touch();

});

function click() {
  if (touchScreen === false) {
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      clicks++;
      console.log(touches);
      console.log(clicks);
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "touches = " + touches + ", clicks = " + clicks;
    });
  }
}
click();
```

```css
html {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<h1><span id="clicks"></span></h1>
```

This code snippet shows that I've "identified" if it's a touchscreen device or not, and executed something based on that info. (FYI when you run code snippet make sure to click/tap on the blank space to receive an output)

However, I don't want to do this because I have many functions that rely on things such as `<button onclick="click()">click</button>`. I'd like to figure a simple way to just change the `onclick` part to `ontouchstart` if it's a touchscreen device. I use JavaScript for my scripting only, Thanks!

Also if you believe there is no way to do so, would there be a better way to check and execute code (with a click or touch) based on if the user has a touchscreen or other device?

edit:

I would normally just do click but some of the items on the page will probably be clicked at a fast rate, or at least faster than 300ms

Comment: Mobile browsers should fire a click event after 300ms; [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wp9anrqa/4/) works in both desktop and mobile Firefox, so your `onclick` attributes should work regardless. Perhaps what you're looking for is [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) to remove the 300ms delay safely.

Comment: that is correct I want to fast click haha, I think this exactly what I needed, I will look into it.

Comment: I would however still like to see a way to either improve my code above or answer my question with a simpler solution, if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could trigger a `click` event on `touchstart`, as such...

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
  // prevent duplicate clicks
  e.preventDefault()

  e.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
))
```

Note though, this is exceptionally fragile because data on the event object — `e` — will not be propagated to the click events.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is I check if `'ontouchstart' in window` and depending on the answer I either subscribe to `touchstart` or `click`.

Something like:

```js
if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
  document.addEventListener("touchstart", () => { /*...*/ });
} else {
  document.addEventListener("click", () => { /*...*/ });
}
```

**EDIT**:
Found more solutions on a [related SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both).