# Checkbox not working on iOS but working on other OS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

My checkbox does not work currently it works on computer as normal but not on IOS. Any help would be appriciated!

```js
function terms_changed(termsbox) {
  if (termsbox.checked) {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```css
#accept {
  width: 700px;
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 80%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<input id="accept" type="checkbox" name="accept" value="1" onclick="terms_changed(this)">
```

Comment: Did you activate the JavaScript-Support of your phone? Afaik it's off by default. SETTINGS > SAFARI > ADVANCED.

Comment: Javascript is enabled on my phone

Comment: Maybe this article answers what you are searching for:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914568/make-onclick-work-on-iphone/18914640

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work either

Comment: lots of question about checkbox in ios device in stackoverflow. please find in stackoverflow if answer did not  get then post your question.