# Meteor: google login doesn't work on iphone/ipad

Tags: javascript, iphone, meteor

I implemented a simple meteor site that uses google login. It works in desktop browsers. In Chrome, I use mobile device emulation and it also works. It also works on an android device I tried. However, it doesn't work on iphone/ipad. I use safari and chrome in iphone/ipad, but neither works. The issue is that when I click the link to login, nothing happens. But in desktop and android, it brings me to the google login page.

I have a test site: http://wwwtest.meteor.com/

It is deployed in debug mode so you can see the files.

Anything special that prevent iphone/ipad to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `cursor: pointer;` style to your `a` element (or catch touchstart/end events as described in the link). It is related to this issue: [how-do-i-use-jquery-for-click-event-in-iphone-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025348/how-do-i-use-jquery-for-click-event-in-iphone-web-application).

After that, it should work. (Checked on ios simulator and it works)