# jQuery window.one("click") Not Working on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a modal that uses jQuery to popup on `(document).ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#openModal").toggleClass("target");
});
$(window).one( "click", function() {
   $( "#openModal" ).toggleClass("target");
});
```

It works fine on desktop, but on iOS Safari it doesn't close on tap.

I read about [the `cursor:pointer` fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025348/how-do-i-use-jquery-for-click-event-in-iphone-web-application), but it doesn't want to work in this scenario. I'm guessing this is because the event is binded to the window while the cursor is binded to the element.

And I obviously can't put `body{cursor:pointer;}`

What could this be caused by ?

Comment: you got `$(window).one("click")`, does this also happen when you change it to `$(window).on("click")`?

Comment: Yes, still doesn't work on mobile, but "on" doesn't make sense for a modal

Answer (score 0):

Using `.one` will only trigger this for the first click on the window, therefore if you tapped (clicked) on the window before the modal opens, the function will not run again. Try using this:

```
$(window).on( "click", function() {
    $( "#openModal" ).toggleClass("target");
});
```

Edit after your response:

I guess you want the modal to open only once on document ready, then do it like this, avoid using toggleClass and use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#openModal").addClass("target");
});
$(window).click(function() {
$( "#openModal" ).removeClass("target");
});
```

Comment: if I use on, every time someone clicks, it will reopen the modal @Alin

Comment: I guess you only want the modal to open only once when the document is loaded ? Then use addClass and removeClass instead of toggle...see my edit.

Comment: Then avoid using .on ('click'... and use .click(function directly, see the update

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).one('click touchstart', function () {
    $( "#openModal" ).toggleClass("target");
});
```