# iOS - Click not firing on element with CSS 3D transformation

Tags: jquery, ios, css, css-transforms

I have been working on a project this weekend which works on IE11, chrome, FF and Android 5.0.

But on the iPad with iOS8 i get some very inconsistent behavior.

http://codepen.io/trgraglia/pen/emrZGP

If you click on the cubes on the corners, the click event is not fired.

SO is making me embed the code.
HTML:

```
<div class="cluster">
  <div id="cube0_1" class="cube popable">
    <!--<div class="bottom"></div>-->
    <div class="face back"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face front"></div>
    <!--<div class="top"></div>-->
  </div>
  <div id="cube1_1" class="cube popable">
    <!--<div class="bottom"></div>-->
    <div class="face back"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face front"></div>
    <!--<div class="top"></div>-->
  </div>
  <div id="cube1_2" class="cube popable">
    <!--<div class="bottom"></div>-->
    <div class="face back"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face front"></div>
    <!--<div class="top"></div>-->
  </div>
  <div id="cube2_1" class="cube popable">
    <!--<div class="bottom"></div>-->
    <div class="face back"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face front"></div>
    <!--<div class="top"></div>-->
  </div>
  <div id="cube2_2" class="cube popable">
    <!--<div class="bottom"></div>-->
    <div class="face back"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face front"></div>
    <!--<div class="top"></div>-->
  </div>
  <div id="cube2_3" class="cube popable">
    <!--<div class="bottom"></div>-->
    <div class="face back"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face front"></div>
    <!--<div class="top"></div>-->
  </div>
  <div id="cube3_1" class="cube popable">
    <!--<div class="bottom"></div>-->
    <div class="face back"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face front"></div>
    <!--<div class="top"></div>-->
  </div>
  <div id="cube3_2" class="cube popable">
    <!--<div class="bottom"></div>-->
    <div class="face back"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face front"></div>
    <!--<div class="top"></div>-->
  </div>
  <div id="cube4_1" class="cube popable">
    <!--<div class="bottom"></div>-->
    <div class="face back"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face front"></div>
    <!--<div class="top"></div>-->    
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cluster {
  position:absolute;
  left:300px;
  top:300px;
}
/* IE does not support preserve-3d. Therefore, the vendor ms comes last and the tranform here needs to be applied to the children for the ms vender prefix. */
.cube{    
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: none;
}
.cube .face {
  width:150px;height:60px;position:absolute;bottom:0;
  outline: 1px solid transparent; /* For FF jagged edges */
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.cube .front {
  background-color:#94BFAC;
  -webkit-transform:  translateZ( 75px );
  -moz-transform: translateZ( 75px );
  -o-transform:  translateZ( 75px );
  transform:  translateZ( 75px );
  -ms-transform:   translateZ( 75px );
}
.cube .back {
  background-color:#BCD8CB;
  border-left:1px solid #BCD8CB;
  -webkit-transform:  translateZ(-75px);
  -moz-transform:  translateZ(-75px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(-75px);
  transform:translateZ(-75px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(-75px);
}
.cube .right {
  background-color:#BCD8CB;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( 75px );
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( 75px );
  -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( 75px );
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( 75px );
  -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( 75px );
}
.cube .left {
  background-color:#A4CCBB;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( -75px );
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( -75px );
  -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( -75px );
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( -75px );
  -ms-transform:  rotateY(90deg) translateZ( -75px );
}

/* translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) on the front and other faces for IE is due to a required offset of the pieces not lining up with the floor. This is not needed if the floor is not used. */
#cube0_1 {
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
  -o-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: none;

  .front {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .back {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0) translateZ(-75px);
  }
  .right {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .left {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-75px);
  }

  .front,
  .back,
  .right,
  .left { height:120px; }

  &.popable:hover .front,
  &.popable:hover .back,
  &.popable:hover .right,
  &.popable:hover .left { height:180px; }
}

#cube1_1 {
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,0);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,0);
  -o-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,0);
  transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,0);
  -ms-transform: none;

  .front {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,0) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .back {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,0) translateZ(-75px);
  }
  .right {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,0) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .left {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,0) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-75px);
  }

  .front,
  .back,
  .right,
  .left { height:210px; }

  &.popable:hover .front,
  &.popable:hover .back,
  &.popable:hover .right,
  &.popable:hover .left { height:270px; }

  cursor:pointer;
}

#cube1_2 {
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,160px);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,160px);
  -o-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,160px);
  transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,160px);
  -ms-transform: none;

  .front {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,160px) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .back {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,160px) translateZ(-75px);
  }
  .right {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,160px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .left {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,160px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-75px);
  }

  .front,
  .back,
  .right,
  .left { height:270px; }

  &.popable:hover .front,
  &.popable:hover .back,
  &.popable:hover .right,
  &.popable:hover .left { height:320px; }

  cursor:pointer;  
}

#cube2_1 {
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,0);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,0);
  -o-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,0);
  transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,0);
  -ms-transform: none;

  .front {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,0) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .back {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,0) translateZ(-75px);
  }
  .right {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,0) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .left {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,0) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-75px);
  }

  .front,
  .back,
  .right,
  .left { height:80px; }

  &.popable:hover .front,
  &.popable:hover .back,
  &.popable:hover .right,
  &.popable:hover .left { height:150px; }
}

#cube2_2 {
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,160px);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,160px);
  -o-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,160px);
  transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,160px);
  -ms-transform: none;

  .front {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,160px) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .back {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,160px) translateZ(-75px);
  }
  .right {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,160px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .left {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,160px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-75px);
  }

  .front,
  .back,
  .right,
  .left { height:70px; }

  &.popable:hover .front,
  &.popable:hover .back,
  &.popable:hover .right,
  &.popable:hover .left { height:130px; }  
}

#cube2_3 {
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,320px);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,320px);
  -o-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,320px);
  transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,320px);
  -ms-transform: none;

  .front {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,320px) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .back {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,320px) translateZ(-75px);
  }
  .right {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,320px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .left {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(0,0,320px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-75px);
  }

  .front,
  .back,
  .right,
  .left { height:80px; }

  &.popable:hover .front,
  &.popable:hover .back,
  &.popable:hover .right,
  &.popable:hover .left { height:130px; }
}

#cube3_1 {
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,160px);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,160px);
  -o-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,160px);
  transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,160px);
  -ms-transform: none;

  .front {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,160px) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .back {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,160px) translateZ(-75px);
  }
  .right {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,160px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .left {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,160px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-75px);
  }

  .front,
  .back,
  .right,
  .left { height:150px; }

  &.popable:hover .front,
  &.popable:hover .back,
  &.popable:hover .right,
  &.popable:hover .left { height:210px; }

  cursor:pointer;
}

#cube3_2 {
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,320px);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,320px);
  -o-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,320px);
  transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,320px);
  -ms-transform: none;

  .front {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,320px) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .back {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,320px) translateZ(-75px);
  }
  .right {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,320px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .left {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-160px,0,320px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-75px);
  }

  .front,
  .back,
  .right,
  .left { height:110px; }

  &.popable:hover .front,
  &.popable:hover .back,
  &.popable:hover .right,
  &.popable:hover .left { height:170px; }

  cursor:pointer;
}

#cube4_1 {
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,320px);
  -moz-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,320px);
  -o-transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,320px);
  transform:rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,320px);
  -ms-transform: none;

  .front {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,320px) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .back {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,320px) translateZ(-75px);
  }
  .right {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,320px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  }
  .left {
    -ms-transform:translate3d(-19px, -11px, 0) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(45deg) translate3d(-320px,0,320px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-75px);
  }

  .front,
  .back,
  .right,
  .left { height:60px; }

  &.popable:hover .front,
  &.popable:hover .back,
  &.popable:hover .right,
  &.popable:hover .left { height:130px; }
}
```

JS - jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cube .face', function(){
  alert($(this).parent().attr('id') + ' ' + $(this).attr('class'));
});
```

All ideas welcome! Thanks.

Comment: I seem to recall that Safari (perhaps IOS specific) does not support individual axis transforms like X, Y Z but only the **combined** version but you'd have to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution makes me nuts!

I needed to add the CSS property and value of `cursor:pointer;` to the clickable areas. Unbelievable!

[How do I use jQuery for click event in iPhone web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025348/how-do-i-use-jquery-for-click-event-in-iphone-web-application/4910962#4910962)

Comment: Unbelievable! Just hit this myself and adding that property makes no sense (but works perfectly in iOS 10.1.1)