# jQuery select click event and safari on iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, iphone, safari, html-select

I got in trouble using the jQuery click event and safari on iPhone. On Windows, the event is fired when I open the select box and once again when I click on an option. On Safari at iPhone its only fired when I open the select box.

The JavaScript code T'm using look like this:

```
$('select').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("data-click") == 1) {
    var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    alert(option);
    $(this).attr("data-click", 0);
  } else {
    $(this).attr("data-click", 1);
  }
});

$('select').focusout(function() {
  $(this).attr("data-click", 0);
});
```

And this is the html code:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The point is, I cannot use `$('select').change()` because I want to fire `alert(option);` when the user opens the select box and even when he click on the same option that was selected before.

[I created a JSFiddle for you to help you understand the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/11hbpnwu/1/) It should alert the item when you open the select box and click on an option.

Comment: Can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025348/how-do-i-use-jquery-for-click-event-in-iphone-web-application